# OpenGL, gluUnProject gives -1.#IND

Tags: c++, opengl

i tried almost everything, copied a lot of codes from different forums but nothing works. What the issue.
I have loop where i draw object from vector. i want to create object where user clicked in 3D space. This is code where i'm trying to do this:

```
if(glfwGetKey( window, GLFW_KEY_F ) == GLFW_PRESS && glfwGetMouseButton(window,     GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT)==GLFW_PRESS && check==false) {
    double x, y;
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &x, &y);
    double mvmatrix[16];
    double projmatrix[16];
    int viewport[4];
    double dX, dY, dZ, dClickY; // glUnProject uses doubles, but I'm using floats for these     3D vectors
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);    
    glGetDoublev (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mvmatrix);
    glGetDoublev (GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projmatrix);
    dClickY = double (1080 - y); // OpenGL renders with (0,0) on bottom, mouse reports with     (0,0) on top
    gluUnProject ((double) x, dClickY, 0.0, mvmatrix, projmatrix, viewport, &dX, &dY, &dZ);
    bricks.push_back(new Cube(0,0,0,1110));
    bricks[bricks.size()-1]->translate(dX, dY, dZ);
    check=true;
}
```

After that operation dX, dY and dZ is -1.#IND. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What are the values you're getting for `viewport`, `nvmatrix` and `projmatrix`? One reason this could be going wrong is if you don't have a current context.

Comment: do not use z = 0.0, make it like 10 or whatever you used as near for projection matrix.

Comment: Values from matrices are some random number. How can i make current context? I have glfwMakeContextCurrent(window) on the top of the code.